# Connecting Raspberry Pi 3b+ to Eduroam network

Tags: wifi, wpa-supplicant

I am trying to connect a raspberry pi to my college network and I'm having trouble finding the right settings to put into `wpa_supplican.conf`. The only thing the IT department was able to tell was that I should verify these settings are correct:

```
EAP method: PEAP

Phase 2 authentication: MSCHAPV2

CA Certification: Do not validate

IP settings: DHCP
```

I've added the following to my `wpa_supplicant.conf`file:

```
network={
        ssid="eduroam"
        key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
        pairwise=CCMP
        auth_alg=OPEN
        eap=PEAP
        identity="soemone@example.com"
        password="xxxx"
        phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
}
```

With these settings I am able to connect to the network but I do not have internet access which makes me think I'm on the right track but there is still something I'm missing.

Comment: Do you get an IP address (`ifconfig wlan0`)?  Do you have a default route (`route`) Some college networks require you to log in / register the device first with IT support and they should always be your first contact as they are responsible for security on the network.

Comment: I do get an IP address @Andrew but its not of the same form as the one I get for my laptop for example and I suppose they should be similar? I don't know about the `route` I'm afraid but I don't believe any registration is required, none of my other devices needed to be registered when I first connected them anyway.

Comment: Can you show the output of the ifconfig and route commands in your question please (just use edit on the question). Also the wpa_supplicant file should be included not the example - hide the user / password info using xxx - where possible copy / paste as quotes and spacing can be important.

Comment: Will do @Andrew. I gave it to someone else to tinker with for now but I'll update the question once I have it back

Comment: Did you find a solution? If so could you post an answer?

Answer (score 0):

At my school you are not allowed to connect to eduroam at your home university. You can connect to an access point but you won't get internet access.